# How can i improve the efficiency of targeting my html elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a menu with links and i have them toggle their hr's opacity to 1 when i click on each link, of course making all other links (hrs) on the menu back to the original opacity of 0 which they previously had (Classic menu UX).

The problem is to achieve this i had to use 2 nested for loops using JS. From what i learned about Big O notation, that isn't very effiecient, especially that with jquery all this code is done in a single line.
My question is how can i improve the efficiency of this code with Vanilla JS only?

HTML

```
<div className="menu">
    <h6>Home<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Movies<hr/></h6>
    <h6>TV Shows<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Documentaries<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Favorites<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Collection<hr/></h6>
</div>
```

JS

```
const menulink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu h6')
for(let item of menulink) {
  item.onclick = () => {
    for(let i=0;i<menulink.length;i++) {
      menulink[i].querySelector('hr').style.opacity = '0'     
    }
    item.querySelector('hr').style.opacity = '1'
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's not as bad as you think. When running the script, it will iterate the links once. Later, when clicking a link, it will iterate the links again. So for each user-action (load, click) you spend a time effort proportional to the number of links.

Comment: right i figured that. Its not that bad for my case. But is there a solution for someone who is building say an online library and each link goes to a different book. That would become a huge loop, can have easily 1000 links. efficiency would thus be pretty bad

Comment: I would just have a variable to store the current active 'hr' element. When someone clicks  to another menu item, set this variable to have an opacity to 0, and then set it to the new 'hr'...you can get the clicked element from the click event, and from there you can query the 'hr'

Comment: please post this aas an answer with a code snippet because i dont fully understand what you mean

Comment: No site would have all those 1000 links in a single page. They would load different sets of links dynamically as the user navigates.

Comment: ok sure. its just an example but it doesn't answer my question. is there a more efficient way to do this or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behold!

```js
const menulink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu h6')
let activeHr;
for(let item of menulink) {
  item.onclick = (event) => {
    if (activeHr) {
        activeHr.style.opacity = '0';
    }
    
    activeHr = event.currentTarget.querySelector('hr');
    activeHr.style.opacity = '1';
  } 
}
```

```css
hr {
opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <h6>Home<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Movies<hr/></h6>
    <h6>TV Shows<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Documentaries<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Favorites<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Collection<hr/></h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve this saving current item:

```js
const menulink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu h6');
let current = null;

for(let item of menulink) {
  item.onclick = () => {
    if (current) current.style.opacity = '0'
    current = item.querySelector('hr')
    current.style.opacity = '1'
  } 
}
```

```css
hr {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <h6>Home<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Movies<hr/></h6>
    <h6>TV Shows<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Documentaries<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Favorites<hr/></h6>
    <h6>Collection<hr/></h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are trying to make your code work - rather than considering the best html and CSS - the use of the hr is unnecessary - all you need is to set the active class on the element and have CSS to apply a border-bottom to it.

So that the headings do not jump on the click - I have added a transparent border under each h6 and then when you click it applies the active class and the styling simply colors the bottom border.

You should not use a html element (hr/) for styling purposes - IMO.

I also disagree with the use of h6's here - these o not appear to be headings.... but I have left it incase there is more to the code than you are showing- eg if they are headings running down the page - but a regualr navigation list would seem to be more appropriate here.

Thanks to @Barmar for the skeleton of the code I have used and I agree with his approach of using the active class. Note that I am using a null check for the removal of the existing active class -although that could be alleviated by simply having the first heading set to active from the start.

```js
const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu h6')

for (let menuLink of menuLinks) {
  menuLink.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.menu h6.active')?.classList.remove('active');
    menuLink.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.menu h6 {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out
}


.menu h6.active {
  border-bottom-color: #000
}

.menu h6:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h6>Home</h6>
  <h6>Movies</h6>
  <h6>TV Shows</h6>
  <h6>Documentaries</h6>
  <h6>Favorites</h6>
  <h6>Collection</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: I have considered this but borders don't transition well on hover hence why i used hrs. The answers above kept my code without changing it thats good practice. But i still appreciate your answer man

Comment: @Uriel Hi - thanks - I have added a transition on hover to transition the color on hover - seems alright to me - the key is to have the transition on the in and the out. I normally have a slightly faster "out" transition than "in"

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover option while styling your heading tags.In hover you can add color of your choice so that whenever you hover on it color will change

Comment: I need JS to set a hr to opacity 1 when i click on it! its not just for hovering

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the style directly, do it through the style of a CSS class. Then you can find the element that currently has the class and remove it, while adding the class to the newly selected element.

```js
const menulink = document.querySelectorAll('.menu h6')
for (let item of menulink) {
  item.onclick = () => {
    let old = document.querySelector('.menu h6 hr.active');
    if (old) {
      old.classList.remove("active");
    }
    item.querySelector('hr').classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.menu h6 hr.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu h6 hr {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h6>Home
    <hr/>
  </h6>
  <h6>Movies
    <hr/>
  </h6>
  <h6>TV Shows
    <hr/>
  </h6>
  <h6>Documentaries
    <hr/>
  </h6>
  <h6>Favorites
    <hr/>
  </h6>
  <h6>Collection
    <hr/>
  </h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first use  instead of h6s if its a navbar and for the amount of links that code ain't inefficient! Cheers mate.